# SQL Query for string with difference of only one character

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to make a query with Laravel, but I think I can not use Eloquent, so I have to use raw queries.

In BD I have a string `name` column that I want to remove about colon before making a query. The string is `My name is: John`

I'm doing the query as `where('name', $name)` nothing of the other world, but in my variable `$name` doesn't have the colon. It's like `$name = My name is John`

I was trying to do a `REPLACE` but i get null

The query is

```
select * from `table` where REPLACE(`name`, ':', '') = 'My name is John' limit 1
```

In Eloquent

```
Model::whereRaw("REPLACE(`name`, ':', '') = '?'", $name)->limit(1)->first()
```

I don't want to use `sounds like` because I have other similar registers and the sounds like according to my experience is very open in that part.

Any recommendations?

Comment: `select replace('My name is: John', ':', '') = 'My name is John'` does evaluate as true, as shown in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5c9d9194ace2d11017ad195fd85438b9)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your query per se https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=810b8fd992878307f495fa4ad619015d

Comment: I just tested it directly in MySQL and if it works too. I'm trying to do it with Laravel, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED:

`DB::raw()` on first term of your `where()`, the second term is the comparison and third term is the filter.

ORIGINAL:

You can use `DB::raw()` on your where. Using eloquent you can do as follows:

```
$filter = 'My name is john';
$result = DB::table('table')->where(DB::raw("replace(name,':', '')"), '=', $filter)->get();
```

The `DB::raw()` function will put the exact term passed on query

Comment: The final consultation being like this
`$result = DB::table('table')->where(DB::raw("replace(name,':', '')"), '=', $name)->first()`